# gradle - plugins {} (script block) vs pluginManager.apply()

Tags: java, gradle

I am applying plugins to a Gradle build script. But there happen to be many ways to doing this.

I found the following two methods for applying plugins to a Gradle project:

1. The DSL for declaring plugins to use in a script i.e. `plugins {}` script block, which I think configures a `PluginDependenciesSpec` object. ([Read this](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.plugin.use.PluginDependenciesSpec.html))

   - Why isn't the `plugins {}` script block shown in the [Script blocks](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.Project.html#N15A7E) section of the `Project` DSL documentation?
2. Calling `pluginManager.apply()` (which applies plugins to a `PluginManager` instance) or calling `plugins.apply()` (which applies plugins to a `PluginContainer` instance) ([Read this](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.Project.html#org.gradle.api.Project:pluginManager))

So for applying, say `org.gradle.java` plugin, I could do the following in a `build.gradle` file:

```
>> pluginManager.apply 'org.gradle.java'

>> plugins.apply 'org.gradle.java'

>> plugins {
    id 'org.gradle.java'
}
```

What are the differences between each?

**PS:** I found this in the [documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.plugin.use.PluginDependenciesSpec.html#N1B688) for `PluginDependenciesSpec`, but then why have so many different methods?

> The plugins {} block serves a similar purpose to the 
>   PluginAware.apply(java.util.Map) method that can be used to apply a 
>   plugin directly to a Project object or similar. A key difference is that 
>   plugins applied via the plugins {} block are conceptually applied to the 
>   script, and by extension the script target. At this time there is no 
>   observable practical difference between the two approaches with regard to 
>   the end result.